# Seg Fault while doing memset

Tags: c++, c++11

While running the below program, I am getting segfault. But if I comment memset, I am not getting seg fault. Not able to figure out the reason. What we can do instead of memset, if I need to clear the structure contents(such as value)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

struct test
{
    int value;
    map<int, int> m;
};

void print(test *ptr)
{
    cout << "map size() : " << ptr->m.size();
    for(auto itr = ptr->m.begin(); itr != ptr->m.end(); ++itr)
    {   
    }   
}

int main()
{
    test obj;
    memset(&obj, 0, sizeof(obj));
    print(&obj);
}
```

Comment: You should have segfault at printing it out. When size() will try to get any internal pointer and it will be zeroed.

Comment: Even though after commenting the printf() still getting seg fault.

Comment: Implement a `clear()` method in the struct, don't memset everything to zero. You don't know what internal state `map` has, it's probably a bad idea to raze it

Comment: @sureshm cpp.sh check: cpp.sh/6sup6 it fails on `print`

Comment: @sureshm You don't need `memset()` to initialize `obj`. C++ isn't C. In fact you'll screw up the internal map member when doing so.

Comment: I agree with Arkady: filling storage of `obj` destroys any contents (with sense) of its members. Where this is non-critical for `int value` its probably lethal for `std::map<int, int> m`. But this comes in effect not before `obj` is used in `print()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::map` is not a POD structure, so it has internals (such as pointers and etc) which will be initialized in it's contructor.

When you call `memset`, you zeroed the entire structure, making any access to it undefined behavior.

And then you call function `size()`, which crash your code, because it tries to read any internal which is at zero address now.

<kbd>[**Live Demo on cpp.sh**](http://cpp.sh/6sup6)</kbd>

Instead of `memset` you should use specified method of `std::map` -> `clear()`, when you want to clear it.

Answer (score 6):

Calling `memset` on a type that is not trivially copyable is undefined behaviour (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset). `std::map` is not trivially copyable, therefore your struct `test` also is not.

If you want to set `value` to 0, you can just call `obj.value = 0`, and if you want to clear `m`, you can call `obj.m.clear()`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::memset` is only intended for objects that are trivially copyable. For something like `std::map` (which is a component of `test`), that's undefined behavior.

While a [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) `int` is going to be an inderminate value, `std::map` has a default constructor and as will start with its own, correct bookkeeping.  But that gets quashed by `std::memset`.

You pretty much don't need `std::memset` in C++.

One quick and dirty option is to [value-initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) `test`.  This zero-initializes values of non-class types such as `int`:

```
test obj{}
```

To reset it you'd do

```
obj = test{}
```

An even better option is to give `test` a default constructor which sets `m` to zero.